# How to get SubMap from HTreeMap in MapDb

Tags: mapdb

How to get SubMap from HTreeMap in MapDb ? We have SubMap function in BTreeMap.

I need to remove different duplicates 10 key data.

key5, value 5 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTreeMap is not sorted, so there is no option to get submap.